# Help with AJAX, Using PHP and hiding elements

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is my first time with AJAX, so I'm a bit confused and need your help. I have four div id's and want to toggle hide/show between them based on result from database.
Sounds simple, eh! But it is hard to implement for me. HELP!.

This is my code -

```
<div id="1">HEya</div>
<div id="2">What's up?</div>
<input type="submit" id='approve' name="action" value="Approve" onclick="a()" class="approve" />
<input type="submit" id='reject' value="Reject" name="action" onclick="r()" class="reject"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//if cookie exists, at the beginning the form should be hidden


if (<?php $responseanswer['response']=='approve'; ?> ){

document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'inline';

}

//if user clicks reject, hide one element dislay another

else if (<?php $responseanswer['response']=='reject'; ?>){
//if cookie exists
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'block';

}

else
{


function a()
{
 var a = document.getElementById('2');

document.getElementById('1').style.display= 'block';


}

//on reject creating a new cookie

function r()
{
 var a = document.getElementById('reject');
 document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display= 'block';


}

}

</script>
```

Eveything is fine, but the div is not hiding.

Comment: What have you already done to make this work? Please only ask Questions on SPECIFIC problems. If you need general guidance look for a good ajax tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (<?php echo ($responseanswer['response']=='approve') ? true:false; ?> == 1 ){

document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = 'inline';

}

//if user clicks reject, hide one element dislay another

else if (<?php echo ($responseanswer['response']=='reject')? true:false; ?> == 1 ){
//if cookie exists
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('onreject').style.display = 'block';

}
```

Edit:

this line `<?php $responseanswer['response']=='approve'; ?>` , doesn't echo nothing to the browser so you're js script will look like 
`if () { some code } else if () { some code }`
However this line `<?php echo ($responseanswer['response']=='reject')? true:false; ?>` echoes 0 or 1 ( false or true ) based on the condition `($responseanswer['response']=='reject')` , so you're js code will look like `if(1 == 1) { some code } else if (0 == 1) { some code }` , now you have some conditions to test in you're js don't you ?

Second edit: use this code and test it out ( change the array value to aprove or reject and see the diferences

```
    <?php $responseanswer = array('response' => 'aprove'); ?>
<div id="1">HEya</div>
<div id="2">What's up?</div>
<br />
<input type="submit" id='approve' name="action" value="Approve" onclick="a();" class="approve" />
<input type="submit" id='reject' value="Reject" name="action" onclick="r();" class="reject"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//if cookie exists, at the beginning the form should be hidden


if (<?php echo ($responseanswer['response']=='aprove')? 1:0; ?> == 1)
{
    document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'inline';

} else if (<?php echo ($responseanswer['response']=='reject')? 1:0; ?> == 1){

    document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'block';

} else {
    function a()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('2');
        document.getElementById('1').style.display= 'block';
        document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function r()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('reject');
        document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('2').style.display= 'block';
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: echo $responseanswer['response'] is reject.

Comment: the element remains as it is.